# How to create dialog with jQuery which disappears after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My buttons class: button-stg

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-stg").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax($(this).attr('href')).done(function(response) {

        });
    });
});
```

How should I append this script if I would like to create a popup or dialog containing "Random text" which disappears after 3 sec?

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery `.fadeOut()`

```
$('.popup').fadeOut(3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gf4vpn9s/3/

or a combination of delay()

```
 $('.popup').delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gf4vpn9s/2/

Comment: Where should I append in my code? And how can I set the popup message text?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use setTimeout funtion on your code like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(dialog).close();
}, 5000);
```

Remember dialog is you modal class or id.